# how to use .js as library in Android Studio?

Tags: javascript, android-studio, shared-libraries

I have a library file .js JavaScript which i have to use them as .jar in android studio. I have no idea on how to use the JavaScript library in android code where i have to access the files from the library. Can anyone give me a solution on how to resolve this problem. I am stuck with this for half a day, any ideas could be useful.

tele-sdk.min.js is the JavaScript library.

Comment: Did you find the solution to it.